# Necesito cambiar \ por / al insertar en BD

Tags: angular, api, typescript

Tengo un problema al insertar una tupla en una base de datos
estoy intentando insertar un valor el cual introduce este carácter \ pero la base de datos no lo reconoce y lo guarda como el string sin ese carácter.

He puesto un:

```
while(valor.indexof("\") !== -1) {
 valor = valor.replace("\", "/")
}
```

Esta es la captura de lo que me aparece

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero le programa lo detecta como algo extraño, AYUDA por favor

Comment: Y dónde está el código que intenta insertar en la base de datos? Porque posiblemente podrías escaparlo para que la BD lo guarde literal y no como alguna expresión. Creo que ese es el verdadero problema :)

Comment: lo que hace es convertir ciertos strings separados de un array en una consulta SQL mediante concats para realizar la consulta y el problema es que dentro de la consulta esta guardando el parametro con "\" y deberia de cambiarlo por "/" pero no se como hacerlo :/

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y amplíala indicando cómo intentas guardar, por qué dices que deberías cambiarlo. De nuevo, es posible indicarle a la BD que use `\\` como literal texto y no como comando, pero si no dices cómo lo estás intentando hacer **mostrando tu código**, no te podemos ayudar. Incluye también la excepción que te muestra.

Comment: La sql que intento hacer es esta:

Update persona set tipo_dap = 1, dap = xxxxxxxx, nie_letter = 0, nombre = 'xxxxx', apellidos = 'xxxxx', password = '9posa2axMG7tHS7y3Q67xQ', masculino = 1, direccion = null, fecha_nacimiento = null, imagen = 'E:\GIT\ProyectoFinDeCurso\dist\apps\api\uploads\image', tipo_persona = 1, LGPD = true, email = 'xxxxx' where email = 'xxxxx'

Esta consulta esta siendo realizada en MySql, pero no permite hacerla me guarda esto: E:\GIT\ProyectoFinDeCurso\dist\apps\api\uploads\image

asi: 
E:GITProyectoFinDeCursodistappsapiuploadsimage

Comment: EDITA la pregunta: usa el enlace que está debajo de la pregunta, que dice 'editar'

Comment: se me ocurre utilizar en vez de "\" un codigo mediante el ascii pero no se como

Answer (score 0):

Ok lo acabo de encontrar, es tan sencillo como esto

```
while (valor.indexOf("\\") !== -1) {
       valor = valor.replace("\\", "/")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar esto que es mas corto y optimo que utilizar un ciclo while:

```js
var valor = "un str\ing con\ cara\cteres";
//si usas el while para recorrer el string mejor usa replace con una expresion liretal
console.log(valor.replace(`/\*/`,''));
// /\*/ busca una o mas coincidencias
```